# Send 404 instead of 405 which is empty WebApplicationException

Tags: java, rest, http, dropwizard

I have dropwizard.io application, and there is a problem with a GET request, my resource looks like:

```
@Path("/foobar")
public class FooBarResource
  (...)
  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  @UnitOfWork
  public Response getFooBar( @PathParam("id") Long id){
    return Response.status(200).entity(FooBarService.get(id)).build();
  }

  @DELETE
  @Path("/{id}")
  @UnitOfWork
  public Response getFooBar( @PathParam("id") Long id){
    return Response.status(200).entity(FooBarService.delete(id)).build();
  }

  @PUT
  @Path("/{id}")
  @UnitOfWork
  public Response getFooBar( @PathParam("id") Long id, FooBar fooBar){
    return Response.status(204).entity(FooBarService.update(id, fooBar)).build();
  }
}
```

And when I send a `GET localhost:port/appPath/foobar/` I have 405 instead of 404. How can I get 404? When I debug my app, all I have is a `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException`, but it's empty.

Comment: What other methods are there that may match a `GET` for localhost:port/appPath/foobar/`?

Comment: Check if this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040222/restful-services-sending-http-405-instead-of-http-500-error

Comment: nope, my app sends 405 in this case, I want it to send 404. I could map an exception, but its full of null values inside.

Comment: Remove `getFooBar`. Make the `GET` request again. What happens? (BTW: please make sure again that you have posted all relevant JAX-RS annotaions on the class)

Comment: still 405, I've updated the class body above

Comment: I think the 405 is as intended. You only specified GET for `foobar/{id}`, and not for `foobar`.

Comment: so I suppose to create another method for all requests, that matches foobar/?

Comment: yep, you need a method without @Path annotation to match that request.

Answer (score 1):

You try GET localhost:port/appPath/foobar/ and you get 405 (Method not allowed). The reason is that this resource (=foobar) exists, so an 404 (resource not found) is wrong. If you create a copy of getFooBar() -> getFooBar2() without path annoation you should get a 200.

If you want you can create a container filter that thows an exception if path is not exactly found. This exception then can be mapped to an 404.

Answer (score 0):

You should use optional path parameters, like described [here](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/)

```
@GET
@Path("/{id:.*}")
@UnitOfWork
public Response getFooBar( @PathParam("id") String id){
    try {
        return Response.status(200).entity(FooBarService.get(Long.parseLong(id))).build();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: still 405, app doesn't even get into the getFooBar method

Comment: looks strange. if you provide request with trailing slash it should be caught with this method. add another one method with \@GET and \@UnitOfWork annotations but without \@Path, it should handle direct GET requests. see [Path docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) for example.